# Присвоить кнопке нажатие клавиши с клавиатуры

Tags: c++, qt

В программе у меня создается кнопка

```
Button *Calculator::createButton(const QString &text, const char *member)
{
        Button *button = new Button(text);
        connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, member);
        return button;
}
Button *equalButton = createButton(tr("="), SLOT(equalClicked()));
```

И теперь я хочу к этой кнопке добавить нажатие с клавиатуры.
переопределил метод

```
void Calculator::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Return || event->key() == Qt::Key_Enter || event->key() == Qt::Key_Equal)
        equalClicked();
}
```

Мне нужно добавить анимацию, что кнопка нажалась или сделать это как-то по другому, но я не знаю как

Comment: Сделал интереса ради [на pyqt](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/46bb6b9f0b02cc8d717ebfc79e228a16f0831963/qt_dummy_calculator_window__with_autodown_button_on_key_press.py)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте в момент нажатия вызвать метод button->setDown(true), а на событие keyReleaseEvent: button->setDown(false).

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#down-prop

Comment: как мне передать в функцию void Calculator::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) свою кнопку?

Comment: Вообщем сделал костыль, если знаете лучше напиши пожалуйста. Сделал глобальную переменную button и туда передал свою кнопку.

Comment: Сохраните указатель на Button* как член класса например.